# Problem with JOINS

Tags: postgresql, join, select, where

I have a problem with my database or query. 
I've three tables, one for videos, another for tags of the videos and other for the tags descriptions and theirs id.

I want to access to the TAG_DES.

For example:

In my table **tags** I have: `tag_id=3` l `tag_des=music`

In my table tag_media I have: `tag_id=3` l `media_id=5`

(it means that the video with id=5 have a tag with id=3, that is music)

So I want to get `tag_des` (music for example) where `media_id=5` by using te tag_id...

This is the image of the tables

[image]

This is the query that I have, but it returns me null i dont know why:

```
SELECT t.tag_des 
FROM media_thumbnail AS m 
    INNER JOIN tag_media as tm 
        ON tm.media_id=5
    INNER JOIN tags AS t 
        ON tm.tag_id=5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use foreign keys and primary keys to join the tables, and then use WHERE clause to filter rows:

```
SELECT     t.tag_des 
FROM       media_thumbnail AS m 
INNER JOIN tag_media as tm 
ON         tm.media_id = m.media_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t 
ON         tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE      m.media_id = 5;
```

Postgres allows to use `USING (join column list)` instead of `ON`:

Quoted from docs:

> The USING clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an equality comparison for each one.

Now you can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT     t.tag_des 
FROM       media_thumbnail AS m 
INNER JOIN tag_media as tm 
USING      (media_id)
INNER JOIN tags AS t 
USING      (tag_id)
WHERE      m.media_id = 5;
```

Have a look at:

Postgres docs:

- [Joins between tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-join.html)
- [Join types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Postgres tutorial:

- [JOINS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm)

Comment: You can using `USING ()` here to clean this up more.